# How do I set image and text edge inset by using storyboard for Button states

Tags: ios, swift, button, storyboard, uiedgeinsets

I want to the image image normal state.

[image]

and for button selected state,

[image]

In the selected state I need a line at the bottom of the button. 
I am setting a image as the button title and I can adjust the positions by using the below section.

[image]

But, my issue is not able to set different Button image/title Edge Insets from story board. Is there any solution by using storyboard.

Comment: On button selected state set image else remove it. you are using button right so use image like the one line in bottom. or use 2 images. one with Underline  and one with empty.

Comment: If I do like that I need to reset the title and image EdgeInsets.